# How can i output a process id in a bash script using jps command?

Tags: bash

I need to create a  bash script in order to return the ip of a process by using jps command.

How can i do that?

i have made so far:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 # script using jps a process id

 jps #returns all the processes with ids and names
 jps -l | grep javaNode #returns again a list of names with ids

  #i need the output of a specific id
```

How can i do that?

Thanks, in advance

Comment: consider editing your post to include the output of `jps -l | grep javaNode`. How will you determine 'the ouput of a specific id' from what is returned. Good luck.

Comment: May you please explain to me what exactly do you mean? Because i didn't understand,thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question and what you are trying to achieve, so I'm trying to point out what you can do to be clearer, and why I think your question is unclear (the 2nd part of my comment). Good luck.

Comment: @programmer - shelter is saying that if you want help parsing the output of a command, you should not assume that everyone knows what that output looks like.

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) the `jps` command you're referring to? Do you only want the number which is the ID? Do you want to select only one of the IDs? What is the criterion for selecting the one you want and excluding the ones you don't?

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at what you want.

```
mynode="mynodename"
id=$(awk -vnode="$mynode" '$2 ~ node { print $1 }' <(jps -l))
echo $id
```